# boto - delete fails because of schema mismatch

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

I have a table called Events, with deviceID as a primary key, and timeStamp as a sort key. Now I'm trying to delete an item given both of these keys:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
events_table = dynamodb.Table('Events')

events_table.delete_item(
    Key = {
       'deviceID'  : 'xyz123',
       'timeStamp' : 12314156.54345
    }
)
```

Why am I getting a schema mismatch error? Output below:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 498,  in do_action
 response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 236, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 500, in _make_api_call
raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: 
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.delete_item):

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

client.delete_item(TableName='tbl_name',
  Key={
       'deviceID':{'S':'xyz123'},
       'timeStamp' : '12314156.54345'
  })
```

Comment: But I'm using the table resource, not the client resource: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.delete_item

Comment: so why are you not using client?

Comment: I guess it is possible, but isn't it supposed to work the same, besides the fact that with client you specify the table name and add the 'S' prefix to strings?

Comment: It is due to ambiguity boto3 documentation. The client part of the documentation say : For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes......Each attribute in an item is a name-value pair. @Eyal Ch  format is the correct schema.